# Lists in formula in Lotus Notes - trying to update each element

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus, lotus-formula

I have a multi-value field where users are able to enter multiple values.  The field is a Name value field which holds the users email address.  I am wanting to have the email address listed as the user's internet address and not as their organization unit/organization address. 
Initially it appears as  "Jane Doe/Sales/USA" and I want to have it listed as Jane.Doe@crown.com

This field will hold multivalues so it could be Jane Doe/Sales/USA; Fred Smith/Sales/KNC; Tom Jones/Accounting/ING

First off, is there a way of getting the internet address to be listed from the names field?  I tried a couple of things that were supposedly going to display the internet address, but it didn't work.

I had a previous single value field and used the following formula to display it as an internet address:
Here is the formula I used.  Hold Name listed the users name as their first name and last name.

```
HoldingLeft := @Left(HoldName; " ");
HoldingRight := @Right(HoldName; " ");
CompleteName := (HoldingLeft + "." + HoldingRight + "@newplace.com");
CompleteName
```

Since I am not familiar with lists in formula language, what is the best way to get the result I am wanting.

Your comments are appreciated.
Thank you,
Jean

Answer (score 3):

This is a way to **convert** the fully qualified names into email addresses:

```
@If(FieldWithNames = ""; 
     ""; 
     @Replace(@Name([CN]; FieldWithNames); " "; ".") + "@newplace.com")
```

Assuming the names field is called `FieldWithNames` then we first test if it's empty. If yes we return an empty string. If no we convert the list of fully qualified names to a list of names only. Then we replace all spaces with "." and add the domain. We are lucky because @Name and @Replace can deal with lists.

This is a way to **read** the internet email addresses from directory for fully qualified names:

```
 @If(FieldWithNames = ""; 
     ""; 
     @NameLookup([Exhaustive]; FieldWithNames; 'InternetAddress'))
```

We are lucky again as @NameLookup accepts as second parameter a list. It reads for every entry the internet email address from directory and returns the result as list.

In **other** cases, you might have to handle every entry of a list separately. Then you'd use [@Transform(list; "variable"; [code doing stuff with variable])](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_TRANSFORM.html)

Comment: Tack FIELD FieldWithNames := onto the front of Knut's second formula, and that's the complete solution in one line of @formula code.

Comment: If the multi-value field contains blank entries, FieldWithNames = "" returns true even if it contains some non-blank lines also. Should use @Trim to remove these, or test !(FieldWithNames != "")